# How can I select top 3 for each group based on another column in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get top 3 most profitable UserIDs in each country in one table using sqlite. I'm not sure where to use LIMIT 3.
Here is the table I have:

```
Country | UserID | Profit
US        1         100
US        12        98
US        13        10
US        5         8
US        2         5
IR        9         95
IR        3         90
IR        8         70
IR        4         56
IR        15        40
```

the result should look like this:

```
Country | UserID | Profit
US        1         100
US        12        98
US        13        10
IR        9         95
IR        3         90
IR        8         70
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pretty simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.profit >= (select t2.profit
                   from t t2
                   where t2.country = t.country
                   order by t2.profit desc
                   limit 1 offset 2
                  );
```

This assumes at least three records for each country.  You can get around that with `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.profit >= coalesce((select t2.profit
                            from t t2
                            where t2.country = t.country
                            order by t2.profit desc
                            limit 1 offset 2
                           ), t.profit
                          );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLite doesn't support *windows function*, so you can write a subquery be a `seqnum` by `Country`, then get top 3

You can try this query.

```
select t.Country,t.UserID,t.Profit
from(
  select t.*,
               (select count(*)
                from T t2
                where t2.Country = t.Country and t2.Profit >= t.Profit
               ) as seqnum
   from T t
)t
where t.seqnum <=3
```

*sqlfiddle:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tmNhRLGG2oKqCKXJEDsjfe/0*

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` won't be usefull as it applies to a whole result set.

I would create an auxiliary column "CountryRank" like this:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Country=Data.Country AND d.Profit>Data.Country)+1 AS CountryRank
FROM Data;
```

And query on that result:

```
SELECT Country, UserID, Profit
FROM (
    SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT() FROM Data AS d WHERE d.Country=Data.Country AND d.Profit>Data.Profit)+1 AS CountryRank FROM Data)
WHERE CountryRank<=3
ORDER BY Country, CountryRank;
```